# Android Dex: [Project name] Cannot create classes.dex file

Tags: android, dex

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4, in my project I'm using few libraries/project:

- ActionBarSherlock
- ViewPagerIndicator
- Volley
- ProgressSherlockFragment
- Google Play Services
- SlidingMenu
- epublib.jar
- gson.jar

I checkouted all projects from SVN and fixed dependencies or missing libraries, but when I try to make my project I'm getting all the time:

```
Android Dex: [Project name] Cannot create classes.dex file
```

No additional warnings/errors. This project works on 2 other computers but on my laptop it doesn't. I can't check Setting on other computers because I don't have access to them right now.

How can I fix this problem or get more details? I have no idea what is wrong.
I tried:

- removing errors/warings in Module Settings
- setting the same API on each projet
- importing them two times from source and with maven
- running IntelliJ as administrator

Comment: Same issue. No idea what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

Found one solution that worked for me:

Remove "readonly" attribute from project folder and inner folders and files

Answer (score 1):

If you have artifacts in your project, then try remove it and then create again. I'm getting same error sometimes after compilation of signed apk

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the DX Wrapper code that is used by IntelliJ. That code can be viewed at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/11.0/org/jetbrains/android/compiler/tools/AndroidDxWrapper.java).

Taking a look at where the error is fired, shows the following code block.

```
String outFile = outputDir + File.separatorChar + "classes.dex";


if (new File(outFile).isFile()) {
    // if compilation finished correctly, show all errors as warnings
    messages.get(CompilerMessageCategory.WARNING).addAll(errors);
    errors.clear();
}
else if (errors.size() == 0) {
    errors.add("Cannot create classes.dex file");
}
```

The problem seems to be that the `outputDir` doesn't have permissions to write the classes.dex. I went into my `Project Structure` and changes the output path from `/target/idea-classes` to just `/target` and that worked like a charm.